# How to use a library to fetch data in Ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am still very new to the world of Ember, and I'm still trying to understand EmberJS and Ember Data (latest version). In my previous (non-Ember) Node app, I included a library that handled all my REST calls to where my data was stored. It set up the connection to the server and handled all the error handling and parsing into a nice and tidy JSON object, and even handled multiple calls to the server in case the response was too big for one call. I can fetch individual records, but if I wanted to fetch a bunch of records, all I had to do was initialize the library object ('myObj') and call myObj.fetchAll(config) to initiate the fetch. Then I just have to wait on several events.

Example

```
myObj.on('record', function() { // Each record is an event }
myObj.on('error', function () { ...}
myObj.on('end', function () { // After the last record is retrieved }}
```

I would very much still like to use this library in Ember, but I have no idea how to go about setting it up. I haven't been able to find any examples of creating my own Adapter (is that the right terminology) that would allow me to do this.

Is this something I can do with Ember, or is it not recommended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly suggest you use ember-data before attempting something non-standard as you're learning. Virtually all the documentation, and help will specifically be about ember-data. This is a good starting point: http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.13.0/models/

It's perfectly possible to use your own models and use a custom rest interface. You initiate your `myObj.fetchAll(config)` call on the router. If it's waiting for an event, return a promise and resolve it when the event returns. I don't know anything about your library but it would look something like:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    return Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve){
      var records = [];
      myObj.on("record", (record) => {
        records.pushObject(record);
      });
      myObj.on("end", () => {
        resolve(records);
      });
      myObj.fetchAll(ENV.config);  
    });
  }
});
```

In imperfect contrast, this is how you glue things together from your adapter to your template normally in ember:

Configuring a REST endpoint:

```
export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  host: 'https://api.example.com'
});
```

Defining a model:

```
export default Model.extend({
  name: attr('string')
});
```

Fetching data in your route:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    return this.store.findAll('person');
  }
});
```

Rendering the data:

```
{{#each model as |person|}}
  {{person.name}}
{{/each}}
```

It's all pretty straight forward if you stick to the default way of doing things.

Comment: @accelerate Obviously a long time ago now but personally I would strongly suggest against using ember-data until you get your head round the rest of ember. It's a lot of learning overhead for very little benefit IMHO.